# Loading from cache UITableView data on Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching, parse-platform

I have a nested query as you can see below and it took 3-4 seconds to load even I use (or I think I use) parse caching. It doesnt't work as I expected. Is there any possibility to loading from cache at first launch and then updating from the parse cloud. Will I need at least core data or sqlite3 for synchronising with parse on local side?

Also when I use  "query.cachePolicy" tableview get duplicated results, how can I use it on proper way.

```
- (void) retrieveSnapsFromParse {

NSString *currentUserName = [PFUser currentUser].username;

PFQuery *retrieveSnaps = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Snap"];
[retrieveSnaps whereKey:@"from" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];

PFQuery *retrieveSnaps2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Snap"];
[retrieveSnaps2 whereKey:@"to" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];

PFQuery * query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[retrieveSnaps, retrieveSnaps2]];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            Snap *snap = [Snap new];

     if([currentUserName isEqualToString:[object objectForKey:@"to"]]) {
                snap.userName = [object objectForKey:@"from"];
                snap.sentOrReceived = @"Received";

                PFFile *snapImageFile = [object objectForKey:@"snappedimage"];
                [snapImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *snapImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        snap.snapImage = snapImage;
                    }
                }];

            } else if([currentUserName isEqualToString:[object objectForKey:@"from"]]) {
                snap.userName = [object objectForKey:@"to"];
                snap.sentOrReceived = @"Sent";

            }


            snap.opened = [object[@"opened"]boolValue];
            snap.counter = [object[@"second"]intValue];
            snap.objectId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.objectId];

            NSDate *createdAt = object.createdAt;
            snap.createdDate = createdAt;

    // Profile image for UICustomTableViewCell
      PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
            [userQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:snap.userName];
             userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork;
            [userQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                if (object) {
                    snap.userFirstName = [object objectForKey:@"firstname"];
                    PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"profileimage"];
                    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                            snap.userProfileImage = image;

                        }

                    }];

                    [snapsTemp addObject:snap];
                }

        snapsTable = snapsTemp;
                    [self.tableView reloadData];

            }];
     }
    }
}];
```

}

The code I use on cellForRowAtIndexPath below;

```
cell.cellUserProfileImage.image = snap.userProfileImage;
```

Also on .m file for mutable array

```
    @implementation SnapsVC
{
    NSMutableArray *snapsTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It start working as I expected after I put below code to cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of retrieveSnapsFromParse

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:snap.userName];
userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork;
[userQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (object) {

        PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"profileimage"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                cell.cellUserProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }

        }];

        cell.cellUserFirstNameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"firstname"];
    }
}];
```